# Extracting Data between two time slots (R)

Tags: r, date, time, difference

I need to extract data in between 2016-03-09 18:54:26 and 2016-03-09 18:55:17 in my data set. So far I tried this.

```
Goo <- with(THhttp , THhttp[ minute(Time) > 54 & hour(Time) == 18 & 55 > minute(Time) & 17 >= second(Time), ] )
```

I know the above gets the data biased because seconds is not in between. So then I tried this (but it still does not get me the result I need):

```
Goo <- with(THhttp , THhttp[ ((minute(Time) > 54 & hour(Time) == 18) & (hour(Time) == 18 & 55 > minute(Time) & 17 >= second(Time)), ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your date/times to epoch integers.  For example, you could create 'lower' and 'upper' as such:

```
lower <- as.integer(as.POSIXct('2016-03-09 18:54:26'))
upper <- as.integer(as.POSIXct('2016-03-09 18:55:17'))
```

And then compare your (epoch'ed) date/time in your data frame with a 
simple " >= lower & <= upper "